# Unsure how to add 'else' after my existing if statement without changing program

Tags: python, if-statement

Have an If-Statement but no 'else' after 'if'. Is the 'else' part necessary? i don't want to change the program (which is supposed to randomise 3 die 50 times and count how many matches there were) unless I need to. Mainly focused on 'else' after if statement

```
#Program 2#
#create a Yatzhee dice program#
import random

print("--------------------")
print("Yatzhee dice program")
print("--------------------")
print("")
print("Welcome to the Yatzhee Dice Program")
print("In this program the dice will get rolled 50 times and at the end we tell you how many matches you got.")
print("")
# before loop #

rolls = 50
total_matches = 0

# --- loop ---

for i in range(rolls): #randomise 50 times#
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)#chooses a number from 1 to 6#
    die3 = random.randint(1, 6)

    print(die1, "|", die2, "|", die3)

    if die1 == die2 == die3:#If all three are the same.#
        print("****MATCH*****")#If statement inside for-loop so it adds up how many matches there were#
        total_matches += 1 #increases no. of matches by 1 each time there is a match#

#after loop#

print("")
print("The total number of matches was:", total_matches)#tells user how many matches there were#
```

Comment: Does your code work? If so, evidently you do not need an else clause. If not, tell us what the problem is.

Comment: My code works but i was just unsure whether I needed an ‘else’ after the if statement

Comment: No. Your code works without one, so clearly you do not need it. An else clause is completely optional.

Comment: If it works, and you don't need to do anything for the case that the numbers are not equal, then I don't see any problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It was just a question of wondering whether or not an ‘else’ was necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have an If-Statement but no 'else' after 'if'. Is the 'else' part necessary?

No, the `else` part is not necessary.

Comment: Would this affect code at all?

Comment: What would affect code?

Comment: Would not having an ‘else’ after my if statement affect my code at all

Comment: You don't need `else`, you can use it if you want to do something in the case the condition is not `True`

Comment: @Harry, You can try the code here  https://onecompiler.com/python/3xrtyynzy

Answer (score 1):

you can use only if 'N' times without using else statement, but it is good practice to use else and elif over if again and again. IF-else is used when we have 2 choice to do

```
if a==True:
   Do something1
else:
   Do something2
```

Adding control flow link for better understanding.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html